# How to use several summary collections in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, summary

I have 2 distinctive groups of summaries. One is collected once per batch another one is collected once per epoch. How can I use `merge_all_summaries(key='???')` to collect summaries in this two groups separately? Doing it manually is always an option but there seems to be a better way.

Illustration of how i think it should work:

```py
      # once per batch 
      tf.scalar_summary("loss", graph.loss)
      tf.scalar_summary("batch_acc", batch_accuracy)
      # once per epoch
      gradients = tf.gradients(graph.loss, [W, D])
      tf.histogram_summary("embedding/W", W, collections='per_epoch')
      tf.histogram_summary("embedding/D", D, collections='per_epoch')

      tf.merge_all_summaries()                # -> (MergeSummary...) :)
      tf.merge_all_summaries(key='per_epoch') # -> NONE              :(
```

Comment: Found this question first, but searched for 2 not distinctive groups of summaries. This Approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42418029/unable-to-use-summary-merge-in-tensorboard-for-separate-training-and-evaluation works a little easier for the slightly different use case. You can simply use the names of the summaries.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Problem solved. `collections` parameter of a summary is supposed to be a list.
Solution:

```
  # once per batch 
  tf.scalar_summary("loss", graph.loss)
  tf.scalar_summary("batch_acc", batch_accuracy)
  # once per epoch
  tf.histogram_summary("embedding/W", W, collections=['per_epoch'])
  tf.histogram_summary("embedding/D", D, collections=['per_epoch'])

  tf.merge_all_summaries()                # -> (MergeSummary...) :)
  tf.merge_all_summaries(key='per_epoch') # -> (MergeSummary...) :)
```

Edit. Syntactical change in TF:

```
# once per batch 
  tf.summary.scalar("loss", graph.loss)
  tf.summary.scalar("batch_acc", batch_accuracy)
  # once per epoch
  tf.summary.histogram("embedding/W", W, collections=['per_epoch'])
  tf.summary.histogram("embedding/D", D, collections=['per_epoch'])

  tf.summary.merge_all()                # -> (MergeSummary...) :)
  tf.summary.merge_all(key='per_epoch') # -> (MergeSummary...) :)
```