# Tensorflow: how to create a new collection for summaries?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I want to create two different collection for summaries. One is for training summary and one is for validation summary.

So i can use two different merge_all operation to store the value

```
merge_all(key=tf.GraphKeys.SUMMARIES)
```

The function scalar can be added to a collection.

```
tf.summary.scalar(
    name,
    tensor,
    collections=None,
    family=None
)
```

how to create a new collection for summaries?

Comment: Maybe that would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722413/how-to-use-several-summary-collections-in-tensorflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to use an arbitrary string value as the key. It might look something like this:

```
tf.summary.scalar('tag_a', ...)
tf.summary.scalar('tag_b', ..., collections=["foo"])
merged_a = tf.summary.merge_all()
merged_b = tf.summary.merge_all(key="foo")
writer_a = tf.summary.FileWriter(log_dir + '/collection_a')
writer_b = tf.summary.FileWriter(log_dir + '/collection_b')
for step in range(1000):
  summary_a, summary_b = sess.run([merged_a, merged_b], ...)
  writer_a.add_summary(summary_a, step)
  writer_b.add_summary(summary_b, step)
```

It's worth mentioning that normally people will configure things in a way where there's one merge_all operation and multiple run calls. For example: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cf7c008ab150ac8e5edb3ed053d38b2919699796/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py#L142 Even if the summary series are broken up using the collections parameter, TensorBoard would still visually represent them as if they're different runs. Please also note that the `name` parameter corresponds to each chart (tag) within a run.